# "This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience. To see this list view, use Salesforce Classic or switch to another list view" error on search

Tags: managed-package, lightning-experience, search, lightninglistview

We are getting '**This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience. To see this list view, use Salesforce Classic or switch to another list view.**' error when trying to search records in a standard 'All' list view of an object (Component of a managed package). Initially when the list view is loaded or If the search keyword is removed, then all of the records are displayed correctly.

This issue is only occurring in some of our sandboxes whereas it's working fine in other sandboxes so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the managed package. This is the standard list view where we have not applied any filter. It's just to show all records & there are less than 50 records in that object.

There is no record type on this particular object. The deployment status of this object is 'Deployed'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Aakriti.G Please refer to this Link - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8lQiSAJ

1. This error was shown because it timed out searching through all the
   data. The workaround was to use an indexed field to filter so it
   doesn't come up with that error.
2. Check if your list view filter has an apostrophe. There is a known
   issue here that looks still unsolved.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Ravi, 1. This doesn't seem to be related to the data issue. Since there are very limited records around 30-35 max. Don't think we need to search it by an index field.
2. This is the standard 'All' list view. There is no filter on this list view.